# Apache Rewrite Rule based on GeoIP

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, reverse-proxy

Currently, I am trying to redirect the domain based on GeoIP. I have already installed the GeoIP module. I am having the below domain.conf file. The issue is that the login is working fine as expected like my example.com will be default for users in India and us.example.com will be the domain when US people access the site. but currently getting

```
redirected you too many times.
```

**Note**: the domain is redirecting as expected but getting the above error. I have used reverse proxy since my application is running in docker on port 8080.

It would be great if someone could give the right apache rewrite rule.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName example.com
       ServerAlias example.com us.example.com
       ProxyRequests Off
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

      GeoIPEnable On
      GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
      GeoIPScanProxyHeaders On


      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}" ^US$
      RewriteRule http://us.example.com$1


      LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined

      ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error_log
      CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in Advanace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^us\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}" ^US$
RewriteRule ^ http://us.example.com [R=302,L]
```

You need to restart apache, and also make sure to clear browser cache before trying to see if the above works.

### Edit:

The OP wanted to redirect all the users that are not from India, to example.co.

Here is the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(?:^|\.)example\.co$
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^IN$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.co [R=302,L]
```

Comment: @Example...it would be great if you give me rule for below stuff..      i have a default domain named example.in. ....it should work with in TLD for only Indian users and outside india it should work like example.co with co TLD

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi so you mean that it should work on *country_tld* depending on country?

Comment: is that possible??

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi you can only mention each rewrite rule manually for each country.

Comment: yes mainly two TLDs here one for only India and One for global users outside India

Comment: ooops...is there no other way to achieve ?

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi oh so you want to use .in for india, and .com for everything else?

Comment: rite..exactly !!! is that really possible??

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi do you want to redirect to the subdomain based on the country code too? So, people from US to us.example.com, etc?

Comment: nope..only two domains example.in for india and example.co for other countries

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi try the new code. I have added it in my answer under the **Edit** section

Comment: in case i am using subdomains the condition should be lik this rite? 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(?:^|develop\.)example\.co$

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi Yes.

Comment: should develop come inside bracket?? i think i missed something?

Comment: @MuneeshDuRaipandi yes. For multiple use: `!(?:^|(?:develop|other|sub|domains)\.)example\.co$`